# How do i merge multiple records into a single record

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a select query:

```
SELECT
  'IT Queue' as Category,
  dbo.Status.Status,
  COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM dbo.Status
  INNER JOIN dbo.CactusQueue_Task ON dbo.Status.Id = dbo.CactusQueue_Task.StatusId
GROUP BY dbo.Status.Status
```

and it outputs the following:

```
+-----------+----------------------------+
| Category  | Status              | Count | 
+-----------+-----------------------------+ 
| IT Queue  | Complete            | 1576  | 
| IT Queue  | Current             | 2     | 
| IT Queue  | Hold                | 7     | 
| IT Queue  | In-Progress         | 56    | 
| IT Queue  | Killed              | 1     | 
| IT Queue  | New                 | 71    | 
| IT Queue  | NTD                 | 1     | 
| IT Queue  | Testing             | 2     | 
+-----------+-----------------------------+
```

would like to modify the query to select a single record like below:

```
+-----------+----------+---------+------+-------------+--------+-----+-----+---------+
| Category  | Complete | Current | Hold | In-Progress | Killed | New | NTD | Testing |
+-----------+----------+---------+------+-------------+--------+-----+-----+---------+
| IT Queue  | 1576     |       2 |    7 |          56 |      1 |  71 |   1 |       2 |
+-----------+----------+---------+------+-------------+--------+-----+-----+---------+
```

How would I go about doing so?

Comment: This is called "pivoting" and there are many ways to do it. Is the number of resulting columns always the same or are they dynamic?

Comment: i am almost confident it would be the same but, lets make it dynamic. i have a `status` table, and each record should be represented as a column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `PIVOT` and dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'', @cols NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';
DECLARE @category NVARCHAR(20) = N'IT Queue';

SELECT @cols = @cols + STUFF((  SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME([Status])
                               FROM dbo.[Status]
                               GROUP BY [Status]
                               FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '');

SET @sql = N' SELECT *
              FROM (SELECT  ''' + @category + ''' Category,
                            s.[Status],
                            q.StatusId
                    FROM dbo.[Status] s
                    INNER JOIN dbo.CactusQueue_Task q
                        ON s.Id = q.StatusId) AS d
  PIVOT (COUNT(StatusId) FOR [Status] IN (' + @cols + ')) AS p;';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: category isnt static, but with a few modifications, i got it working using your code. thanks for the help. didnt know what it was called either so thanks for that too =)

Comment: @highboi yeah, I figured it wasn't, but your sample data used static data for it, so I went with that

Answer (score 2):

Although @Lamak answer is a good solution I'd suggest another approach using CASE statement.

```
SELECT 'IT Queue' as Category,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN dbo.Status.Status = 'Complete' THEN 1 END AS Complete,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN dbo.Status.Status = 'Current' THEN 1 END AS Current,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN dbo.Status.Status = 'Hold' THEN 1 END AS Hold,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN dbo.Status.Status = 'In-Progress' THEN 1 END AS In-Progress,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN dbo.Status.Status = 'Killed' THEN 1 END AS Killed,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN dbo.Status.Status = 'New' THEN 1 END AS New,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN dbo.Status.Status = 'NTD' THEN 1 END AS NTD,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN dbo.Status.Status = 'Testing' THEN 1 END AS Testing
FROM   dbo.Status
INNER  JOIN dbo.CactusQueue_Task 
ON     dbo.Status.Id = dbo.CactusQueue_Task.StatusId
```

Comment: but...but..."i am almost confident it would be the same but, lets make it dynamic"

Comment: @Lamak I was just writing it when your answer show up!!!